# SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Cannot Connect to Server Instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've installed SQL Server 2008 Developer edition x64 on Windows 7 Prof 64.  The installation seems to have been successful, but I

cannot connect SQL Server Manager to to instance on the same computer.  I use this computer for developement, so SQL Server and

Visual Studio 2008 are (or will be) on the same computer.

When I try to connect to either  or SONYSQL08, I receive this error:

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to SONYSQL08.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Here are some further details:

Visual Studio 2008 is not installed yet.
I am logged on with an admin account (at least I can change the time)

SQL Server Browser is running
Windows Authentication
SQL Server instance SONYSQL08 is running

Where SONYSQL08 is the name of the SQL Server instance, the command

The command sqlcmd -S SONYSQL08       yields

HResult 0x35, Level 16, State 1
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. 
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while

establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL

Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Login timeout expired.

The server configuration is:

Name    State   Start Mode  Log On As   Process ID  Service Type
SQL Server Integration Services 10.0    Running Automatic   NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE  2052
SQL Server Analysis Services (SONYSQL08)    Running Automatic   NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE  2228    Analysis Server
SQL Server (SONYSQL08)  Running Automatic   LocalSystem 2308    SQL Server
SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (SONYSQL08)    Running Manual  NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE  3828
SQL Server Reporting Services (SONYSQL08)   Stopped Manual  NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE  0   Report Server
SQL Server Agent (SONYSQL08)    Stopped Manual  LocalSystem 0   SQL Agent
SQL Server Browser  Running Automatic   NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE  2804

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I can get this working?

Could remote connections be the problem when the instance is running on the same computer? If so, how can I enable remote connection when I cannot connect?

Thanks
MIke Thomas

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you have a named instance called SONYSQL08 on the machine.  You need to connect to COMPUTERNAME\SONYSQL08 instead of SONYSQL08.

Comment: You have got to be kidding me.  That was the answer - you don't know how much I appreciate this one.
Mike Thomas

Comment: No problem.  Don't forget to mark answers as the correct one.

Comment: i've been searching for hours!! thankyou!!